# How can I create a a flyout multi column menu?

Tags: css, menu, navigation

I already have a horizontal menu for my site and I am wanting just the fly out part of the multi column menu. Here is an example of what I am wanting to do: http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/pro-flyout-list.html

Is there a site that has a tutorial on how to do it, or some kind of generator? I want my current menu to stay in tact ( http://veterinarycare.atspace.cc/ ). I just want to be able to hover and have the fly out multi column part. It seems with the ones I've seen, I have to implement their horizontal/vertical bar and it makes it confusing on how to separate the parts to make it work with mine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where to find a tutorial, but here's a (very) general guide.

First, you want to arrange your nav bar and the flyout as a series of nested lists, sort of like this:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        <ul class="flyout">
            <li><a href="#">Sublink 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sublink 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sublink 1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then, in your CSS, you make sure you style the flyout like so:

```
.flyout{
    display:none;
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

Then, when you hover over the parent li element, you make sure the flyout appears.

```
li:hover .flyout{
    display:block;
    visibility:visible;
    /* snip */
}
```

Then, it's just a matter of positioning everything correctly, adding styles, and generally making the navbar look fancy.

I would try relatively positioning the flyout, and pushing it down using `top:16px` or something like that.  You might also want to try to change the positioning of the parent `li` or change how it handles overflows in CSS so that it doesn't balloon out of control.

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Deflect/KXHn8/